# Undefined Definition in LEX program

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compiler-construction, ubuntu-14.04, lex

I am trying to create a lex scanner that reads through a header file and then finds lexical errors and writes them to a text output but I keep running into a undefined error on the lines that contain the tokens {line} and {punc}.  I'm completely new to lex so I have not been able to identify quite what is missing.  Here is part of my code so far that has the errors:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <ctype.h>      
#include "tokens.h"

%}

%{ option noyywrap 
%}

ws       [ \t\r]+

%%

[ \t\n]          ;
.                printf("Unexpected Character\n");
:                return COLON;
{ws}     { ECHO; }                       
{line}   { ECHO; Listing::nextLine();}   
"<"      { ECHO; return(RELOP); }        

begin    { ECHO; return(BEGIN_); }  

{punc}   { ECHO; return yytext[0]; }   

.        { ECHO; Listing::appendError(LEXICAL, yytext); } 

%%


int main() 
{
    yylex();
}
```

Comment: `line` and `punc` aren't defined anywhere that I can see. What do you think they mean, and why?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define `line` and `punc` in the initial section, just as you did with `ws`. The error is telling you that it couldn't expand `{line}` and `{punc}` because there was no definition for those two identifiers.

Comment: Thanks so MUCH!  I have been staring at all my files in conjunction with this one and didn't see that glaring mistake staring me in the face!  I will attribute it to sleep deprivation!  Thanks again!